# convert composite C++ struct (containing vectors) to VB using DLL

Tags: c++, vb.net, dll, vector, struct

I have a problem with my composite c++ struct conversion to VB through DLL.

I used simple function

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int Function()
{return 4;}
```

in C++ and read it easily on VB with this code

```
<DllImport("dlltest.dll", EntryPoint:="Function", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)>
    Private Shared Function AddFunction() As Integer
    End Function
```

The problem begins when I try to read my other function, which returns a structure:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) info Func()
{
    ...
    info K;
        ...
    return K;
}
```

I use this to import this function to VB

```
<DllImport("dlltest.dll", EntryPoint:="Func", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)>
    Private Shared Function AdFunction() As info
    End Function
```

I described the structure info in C++ as follows:

```
struct time
{
    double start;
    double duration;
    double finish;
};
struct busy
{
    time T;
    int operation;
    int product;
    int order;
};
struct operation
{
    string name;
    int lane;
    time T;
    int parallel;
    int coherent;
    int product;
};
struct product
{
    string name;
    int quantity;
    int o;
    vector<operation> O;
    int levels;
    vector <double> LevelTime;
};
struct order
{
    int id;
    int p;
    vector<product> P;
    string date;
};
struct lane
{
    string name;
    int t;
    int b;
    vector<time> T;
    vector<busy> B;
    operation O;
};
struct info
{
    vector <lane> L;
    int l;
    vector <order> O;
    int o;
};
```

I have described the same structure in VB language but the program couldn't read my info. I can also show the VB structure.

```
Public Structure time
    Public start As Double
    Public duration As Double
    Public finish As Double
End Structure
Public Structure busy
    Public T As time
    Public operation As Integer
    Public product As Integer
    Public order As Integer
End Structure
Public Structure operation
    Public name As String
    Public lane As Integer
    Public T As time
    Public parallel As Integer
    Public coherent As Integer
    Public product As Integer
End Structure
Public Structure product
    Public name As String
    Public quantity As Integer
    Public o As Integer
    Dim OO As operation
    Public levels As Integer
    Dim LevelTime As Double
End Structure
Public Structure order 
    Public id As Integer
    Public p As Integer
    Dim PP As product
    Public date As String
End Structure
Public Structure lane 
    Public name As String
    Public t As Integer 
    Public b As Integer
    Dim TT As time
    Dim BB As busy
    Public O As operation
End Structure
Public Structure info
    Dim TT As lane
    Public t As Integer
    Dim OO As order
    Public O As Integer
End Structure
```

This may be too much irrelevant text, but I really like to know how I could fix the conversion problem. Thanks in advance and sorry if my English skills seem bad :).